# how to get Ids In to list of array in c#

Tags: c#, linq

i have an array like this.

```
public const string ProviderRoles = "ProviderAdmin,ProviderUser";
```

first i want to get the their respective id's from database say table "roles"
 secondly i want to arrange those ids in to list like this.

```
List<int> roleidprovider = new List<int>() { 6, 7 };
```

here in above example

```
ProviderAdmin id = 6,
ProviderUser id = 7
```

can some one help me on doing this

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: There should be enough tutorials out there that teach you how to read data from a database - have you tried any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var providerroles = AppConstants.ProviderRolesonly.Split(',').ToArray();
            List<int> providerroleIds = new List<int>();
            foreach (var id in providerroles)
            {
                providerroleIds.Add(rolesService.GetWhere(a => a.RoleName == id).Select(a => a.Id).First());
            }

 List<int> roleidprovider = providerroleIds;
```

AppConstants.ProviderRolesonly is the place where all role name strings were saved.

Answer (score 0):

How you get data from the DB, the steps depends on what ORM you use. Like EF or ADO.NET etc.
And you can use LINQ query to get the Id's from your Role table with a where clause of your Array contents.

Then you can use a for loop or LINQ (again) to match the Array values to ID's from the DB.

Comment: works perfect.var providerroles = AppConstants.ProviderRolesonly.Split(',').ToArray();
            List<int> providerroleIds = new List<int>();
            foreach (var id in providerroles)
            {
                providerroleIds.Add(rolesService.GetWhere(a => a.RoleName == id).Select(a => a.Id).First());
            }    List<int> roleidprovider = providerroleIds;

Comment: above is the way how is resolved. thanks Vijay on this.